# PHP Confirmation Popup upon user login

Tags: php, jquery, popup

I have a problem, that I can not get to solve.
I have made a simple php login script, that is using a SQL Database to get the login data. If you login you should get a popup and then it should redirect to the main page again. I can not get it working. This is my current code:

```
<?php
        session_start();
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users', 'root', '');

        if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $passwort = $_POST['password'];

            $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username");
            $result = $statement->execute(array('username' => $username));
            $user = $statement->fetch();

            if ($user !== false && password_verify($passwort, $user['password'])) {
                $_SESSION['userid'] = $user['id'];
                echo 'href=# class="big-link" data-reveal-id)"myModal"';
                die('Login erfolgreich. Weiter zu <a href="geheim.php">internen Bereich</a>');
            } else {
                $errorMessage = "E-Mail oder Passwort war ungültig<br>";
            }
        }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Login</title>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.reveal.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet"  type ="text/css" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
          if(isset($errorMessage)) {
             echo $errorMessage;
            }
        ?>
        <a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal">
            Fade and Pop
        </a>    s
    <div class="Header">
        Login
</div>
    <div class="Navbar">
            <a href="./index.php">Main</a>
            <a href="./uebersicht.php">Übersicht</a>
            <a href="./login.php">Login</a>
        </div>
    <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
        <h1>Login erfolgreich</h1>
        <p>Du wirst gleich weitergeleitet</p>
        <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>
    <div class="Login">
        <form action="?login=1" method="post">
            <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="Username">Benutzer   </label>
                <input id="Username" type="text" name="username">
            </li>
            <li><label for "Password">Passwort      </label>
                <input id="Password" type="Password" name="password">
            </li>
            <li>
                <button>anmelden</button>
            </li>
            </ul>   
        </form>        
</body>
</html>
```

Im using "Reveal" Modal popups for my popup. The popup itself works by clicking the href in the

Edit: the relevant part of my styles.css

```
.reveal-modal-bg { 
    position: fixed; 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    z-index: 100;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0; 
    }

.reveal-modal {
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 100px; 
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -300px;
    width: 520px;
    background: #eee url(modal-gloss.png) no-repeat -200px -80px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    padding: 30px 40px 34px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    -box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    }

.reveal-modal.small         { width: 200px; margin-left: -140px;}
.reveal-modal.medium        { width: 400px; margin-left: -240px;}
.reveal-modal.large         { width: 600px; margin-left: -340px;}
.reveal-modal.xlarge        { width: 800px; margin-left: -440px;}

.reveal-modal .close-reveal-modal {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: .5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 11px;
    color: #aaa;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rbga(0,0,0,.6);
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Comment: You're not showing the modal in your success. `$('#myModal').modal('show')` This is for JS btw not PHP

Comment: $('#myModal').modal('show') will work with bootstrap based UI frameworks. Not sure what is there inside styles.css because "jquery.reveal.js" (modal plugin in jQuery) is being used here.

Comment: This is the relevant part of my styles.css:

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will resole your issue but, you can give it a try

```
<a href="#" id="open_modal" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal">Fade and Pop</a>

<?php if(isset($errorMessage)) { 
  echo $errorMessage;
} else {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#open_modal').click();
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

And also you should be using the latest JQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Another thing is, it makes life easier if you use [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/) when you want to work with modals

Comment: Actually I dont want the "Fade and Pop" to appear on the website, I just pulled it off the example code.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `PHP` code  while checking for valid user credentials:

```
if ($user !== false && password_verify($passwort, $user['password'])) {
                $_SESSION['userid'] = $user['id'];
                $successMessage = "<script>$('a.big-link').trigger('click');</script>";
                die('Login erfolgreich. Weiter zu <a href="geheim.php">internen Bereich</a>');
            } else {
                $errorMessage = "E-Mail oder Passwort war ungültig<br>";
            }
```

HTML page modifications:

```
<body>
        <?php 
          if(isset($errorMessage)) {
             echo $errorMessage;
            }
          else if(isset($successMessage))
             echo $successMessage;
        ?>
```

Comment: That doesnt seem to work, I still dont get the popup. Basicly what I want to do is, uppon loggin in successfull, I want to get a confirmation popup an then it should redirect to another page.

Comment: Use of undefined constant successMessage - assumed 'successMessage' in C:\xamp\htdocs\login.php on line 36 is what I get. Also tried moving the $successMessage variable directly behind the session_start()

Comment: I think "$" symbol before variable name was missed...u mind putting "$" before successMessage (if not present already) and trying?

Comment: Okay...It was due to reason that isset() wasn't present and first time variable wasn't set...Modified the answer